# Using MAPE in k fold cross validation sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

Need to use MAPE instead of R2 in a cross validation, just wanna know if there's any easy equivalent to

```
score = cross_val_score(reg, X, y, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_percentage_error', cv=kfold)
```

I saw sklearn listed MAPE as a scoring method [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html) but when I tried to do the above code I got this error

`'neg_mean_absolute_percentage_error' is not a valid scoring value`

Comment: yeah that's newly added. What's `import sklearn; print(sklearn.__version__)` for you? Probably <= 0.23.*? You might want to upgrade

Comment: That was actually the case, thanks, unluckily my company has version control so I might have to work around lol

Comment: :) you can pass a callable to `scoring` yes.

Comment: It's also worth noting as a possible workaround depending how much effort you need to put in, you can use [make_scorer()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html#sklearn.metrics.make_scorer) and [the source code for your preferred function](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09b/sklearn/metrics/_regression.py#L291) to make a custom scoring function

Comment: I have added some helper code with the `make_scorer` approach for implementing NMAE. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(EDIT: Edited for NMAPE instead of NMAE)

You can use [sklearn.metrics.make_scorer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring) over a custom function to get what you need. Here is some helper code below.

The definition of NMAPE is defined based on the formula from [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/294069/293379). It's simply the negative of the below equation -

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

#define custom function which returns single output as metric score
def NMAPE(y_true, y_pred): 
    return 1 - np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)) * 100

#make scorer from custome function
nmape_scorer = make_scorer(NMAPE)

#dummy data
X = np.random.random((1000,10))
y = np.random.random(1000,)

#cross validation score on model
reg = LinearRegression()
cross_val_score(reg, X, y, scoring=nmape_scorer, cv=5)
```

```
array([-4453.67565485,  -148.201211  ,  -222.92820259,  -185.27855064,
        -657.27927049])
```

Comment: Thanks - that looks good! Just took a look at the description of neg MAPE and realised that instead of giving positive values with 1 being the best prediction, it is computed differently as a loss function(which i kinda don't understand lol). Do you know if I can check its actual formula anywhere or the MAPE is just 1+negMAPE?

Comment: as far as I understand, NMAPE or NMAE are simply just a inverse of the MAPE or MAE. So if MAE then its multiplied by -1, if MAPE its reduced from 1. Let me see if i can find a relevant source for this.

Comment: I was going through the source code for `make_scorer`. Search for "neg_mean_absolute_percentage_error" and you will find that its basically using the  `mean_absolute_percentage_error` with a parameter "greater_is_better=False`. On further inspection, you can see how the rules of flipping the sign work. Details here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09b/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py#L578